# Set flags to methods on java

Tags: java, class

My teacher wants to run something like this "java Methods -r fact 3" to get the results of a factorial 3 and be able to change -r to -d to show the process of getting to the result instead of just the result.

I can't find how to "assign" the -r or -d to each class or what is the name of that. Can someone please help? I'm new in all of this.

Comment: ie. command line arguments? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Yes, kinda like that. So I have two classes, for example factorial and factoriald, how would I make "-r" to run factorial and -d to run factoriald ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `args` array of the `main` method holds the command line arguments. The `-r` or `-d` will be at position 0 of `args`. You want something like this:

```
public static class CalculateFactorials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args[0].equals("-r")) {
            factorial();
        }
        else if (args[0].equals("-d")) {
            factoriald();
        }
    }
    public static void factorial() {
        //calculate factorial
    }
    public static void factoriald() {
        //calculate factorial while showing process
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For this to work, factorial and factoriald would have to be on the same file, right? I have them on separate ones but I believe I can just copy and paste both methods on the main one.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to have them in the same file. If they are two different class files, you can either create the objects and call the appropriate method via `object.method()`, or if the methods are static methods, you can call them without creating the objects, like `ClassName.staticMethod()`.

Comment: Thank you i tried to write:
`if (args[0].equals("-r") && args[1].equals("fact")) {
                fact(); ` 
but it says "method call expected" on the fact line. I tried to copy the code of fact below but it didn't work. I also tried to write `fact.staticMethod(); `  and it cannot resolve staticMethod, I'm not sure if I'm doing everything wrong.

Comment: `fact.class();` sorry

Comment: @Abby You wouldn't actually write `fact.staticMethod()`, that was just an example. Is it mandatory that the classes that calculate the factorial be in a separate file? If not, you can call static methods in the same file like in [this example](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program).

Comment: Yes, sorry I realized that after I wrote it. No it isn't mandatory, i tried this:
`if (args[0].equals("-r") && args[1].equals("fact")) {
                fact();` and copied the method that calculates factorial right below but it says Method call expected with a red underline for `fact();`, I'm not sure why.

Comment: the class for factorial starts like this `public class fact {` I don't know if there's a problem with it.

Comment: @Abby See my edit. It does it in the same file. What you are doing does not work because the class name is the same as the method name.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help and patience with me :)